# jQuery highlight specific <a> when dropdown menu opens

Tags: jquery

I want to change the color of toggle button a tag when the dropdown menu opens. Unfortunately, all of the  tag get highlighted. I wanted to target specific  tag.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.dropdown-menu').not($(this).next('.dropdown-menu')).fadeOut()
        $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').fadeToggle().toggleClass('isOpen');

        if ($('.dropdown-menu').hasClass('isOpen')) {
            $(this).html("-"); 
            $(".sidebar-collections .sdc-element ul li a").css("color", "#f37727");
        } else {
            $(this).html("+");
            $(".sidebar-collections .sdc-element ul li a").css("color", "#000");
        }
    });
});
```

This is my issue

[image]

```
<li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title | escape }}</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Test</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Test</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Test</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Test</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Test</a></li>       
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>
```

I want to highlight the specific a href when my dropdown is open then if close, it will go back to color black.

Comment: Can you please post the HTML code as well. I have the answer, but waiting for the HTML to post the correct one.

Comment: @RijoKP i've updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the element just left of the clicked button, you can use following code:

```
$(function() {
        $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.dropdown-menu').not($(this).next('.dropdown-menu')).fadeOut()
            $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').fadeToggle().toggleClass('isOpen');

            if ($('.dropdown-menu').hasClass('isOpen')) {
                $(this).html("-"); 
                //$(".sidebar-collections .sdc-element ul li a").css("color", "#f37727");
                $(this).siblings('a').css("color", "#f37727");
            } else {
                $(this).html("+");
                //$(".sidebar-collections .sdc-element ul li a").css("color", "#000");
                $(this).siblings('a').css("color", "#000");
            }
        });
    });
```

Please let me know if you still want improvements.

Comment: Rijo -- Devesh also answered children. you use sibling which is also works. can we say this is the most flexible one? Haider Ali answered $(this).prev().css("color", "#f37727"); which also works.

Comment: I think there is no 'children' option with $(this) element here. (Sorry @Devesh) just pointed what I have tested.

Comment: will these code not affect any of a href in other parts of the page?

Comment: It should not since we target the specific element.

Comment: Rijo - I really appreciated your help! God bless you! I will choose your answer and use it to my project. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you Kobe :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
  $(this).children(".sidebar-collections .sdc-element ul li a").css("color", "#f37727");
```

Comment: Devesh - do you mean in order to my issue is to use each() to target specific a href?

Comment: Yes, you have to look for your specific href matching attribute and then change the color. As of now your selector is selecting all the tags with a

Comment: Devesh - is this right? $(".sidebar-collections .sdc-element ul li a").each(function() {
       $(this).css("color", "#f37727");
      })

Comment: @KobeBryan i have updated my answer. You can only look for the child element of the current clicked element to change the color.

Comment: Devesh - the one answers .siblings not children. also works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the color through css, while the target toggle button color can be changed with jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.dropdown-menu').not($(this).next('.dropdown-menu')).fadeOut()
        $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').fadeToggle().toggleClass('isOpen');

        if ($('.dropdown-menu').hasClass('isOpen')) {
            $(this).html("-"); 
            $(this).prev().css("color", "#f37727");
        } else {
            $(this).html("+");
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar-collections .sdc-element ul li a {
   color:#000;
}
```

Comment: Haider - it's not working because the target highlight is outside dropdown div.

Comment: you want to change the color of drop down list which is toggled? right

Comment: no. when toggled, the a href on top of dropdown menu should be highlighted. check my html.

Comment: Oh OK. let me see

Comment: you mean the toggle button

Comment: yeah toggle button.

Comment: Haider -- your code works but Rijo code also works. Idk which is the most flexible code that may not error in other aspects.

Comment: siblings and prev are just two approcahes to reach to the target <a/> tag  if it works, its good can use both. However, you need to apply the css through style tag

Comment: Haider -- right. is there any advantage prev compared to sibling?

Comment: Haider -- thank you so much for your help! I really appreciated your help! God bless you!